# Draw a square wave using Mathematica for a long range

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to get a continuous square wave use the software mathematica.

```
Plot[SquareWave[{0, 10}, x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Red]]
```

However, if I set the xmax to be 100,the picture will be out of expectation.

```
Plot[SquareWave[{0, 10}, x], {x, 0, 100}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Red]]
```

Here is the result:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfWVK.png)

What about another way to generate a square wave? I didn't remember where I saw,but I know we can use `UnitStep`.

However, it still exists the problem out of expectation.

```
Plot[10 UnitStep[-Sin[0.4 Pi t]], {t, 0, 200}, Exclusions -> None, 
PlotStyle -> Thick]

Plot[10 UnitStep[-Sin[0.4 Pi t]], {t, 0, 500}, Exclusions -> None, 
PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPRLc.png)

Actually,the square wave generate is used as the clock signal, so I hope it stable, continuous.

Hope you could help me to slove this problem. Hear from you soon.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `SquareWave`. The trouble is `Plot` does a fairly coarse initial sampling and doesn't detect all the discrete regions.  You simply need to give `Plot` a `PlotPoints` specification:

```
  Plot[SquareWave[{0, 10}, x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
        ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Red]]
```

`PlotPoints` needs to be set large enough so that the initial sampling hits every interval.

Alternately you can explicitly provide the points to plot and use  `ListLinePlot`

```
 ListLinePlot[
    Flatten[Table[
        {{i,10},{i+1,10},{i+1,0},{i+2,0}} , 
           {i, 0, 100, 2}], 1]]
```

I don't see straight away how to apply the dashing in this case though.

Comment: Thank you a lot! And with your help, success has been achieved.